# Dovecot can't login Virtual user

Tags: linux, email-server, dovecot, login

Hello im running `Linux <hostname> 4.9.0-11-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.189-3+deb9u1 (2019-09-20) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Im totally new to setting up mailservers.
I havesetup a postfix for SMTP and it can receive emails.
Postfix version is `mail_version = 3.1.12`

I have also installed Dovecot version:`2.2.27 (c0f36b0)`
My configuration is such that POSTFIX is configured to use DOVECOT SASL through local socket.

My system is configured to store emails in `/var/mail/<owndomain.org>/<username>`. For each domain i have my own passwd file where dovecot is supposed to lookup usernames and passwords.
`/var/mail/<owndomain.org>/passwd`.

I have created `virtualuser` for accessing mails and authenticating users.
My dovecot configuration is:
In `/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf` i have added at the end of the file

```
userdb {
  driver = passwd-file
  args = username_format=%n /var/mail/%d/passwd
  default_fields = uid=virtualmail gid=virtualmail home=/var/mail/%d/%n
}
passdb {
  driver = passwd-file
  args = username_format=%n /var/mail/%d/passwd
}
```

passwd file contents are in format:

```
<username_without_domain>:{plain}test
```

In `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-auth.conf` i have set:

```
disable_plaintext_auth = no
auth_mechanisms = plain login
```

In `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf` i have set:

```
mail_home = /var/mail/home/%d/%n
mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/spool/mail/%d/%n
mail_privileged_group = virtualmail
```

**Now the problem:** I was testing the configuration using telnet. POSTFIX receives email, stores it. No problem. When i tried to log in onto Dovecot IMAP using Telnet i get this message:

```
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE AUTH=PLAIN AUTH-LOGIN] Dovecot ready.
a login "username@owndomain.org" "test"
a NO [UNAVAILABLE] Internal error occured. Refer to server log for more information.
```

I have enabled verbose logging and this is the output of logs:
`/var/log/dovecot.log` had this message:

```
Nov 16 14:20:49 auth: Error: plain(username@owndomain.org,192.168.9.131,<RF4llXaXisPAqAmD>): user not found from any userdbs
Nov 16 14:20:49 imap: Error: Authenticated user not found from userdb, auth lookup id=684589057 (client-pid=9601 client-id=1)
```

`/var/log/dovecot-debug.log` had this message:

```
Nov 16 14:20:18 auth: Debug: Loading modules from directory: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/auth
Nov 16 14:20:18 auth: Debug: Read auth token secret from /var/run/dovecot/auth-token-secret.dat
Nov 16 14:20:18 auth: Debug: auth client connected (pid=9601)
Nov 16 14:20:47 auth: Debug: client in: AUTH    1       PLAIN   service=imap    session=RF4llXaXisPAqAmD        lip=192.168.2.2 rip=192.168.9.131       lport=143       rport=$
Nov 16 14:20:47 auth-worker(9603): Debug: Loading modules from directory: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/auth
Nov 16 14:20:47 auth-worker(9603): Debug: pam(username@owndomain.org,192.168.9.131,<RF4llXaXisPAqAmD>): lookup service=dovecot
Nov 16 14:20:47 auth-worker(9603): Debug: pam(username@owndomain.org,192.168.9.131,<RF4llXaXisPAqAmD>): #1/1 style=1 msg=Password:
Nov 16 14:20:49 auth: Debug: passwd-file /var/mail/owndomain.org/passwd: Read 2 users in 0 secs
Nov 16 14:20:49 auth: Debug: passwd-file(username@owndomain.org,192.168.9.131,<RF4llXaXisPAqAmD>): lookup: user=username file=/var/mail/owndomain.org/passwd
Nov 16 14:20:49 auth: Debug: client passdb out: OK      1       user=username@owndomain.org
Nov 16 14:20:49 auth: Debug: master in: REQUEST 684589057       9601    1       a61dd67ee43390596ddf86e6c08db6f9        session_pid=9604        request_auth_token
Nov 16 14:20:49 auth-worker(9603): Debug: passwd(username@owndomain.org,192.168.9.131,<RF4llXaXisPAqAmD>): lookup
Nov 16 14:20:49 auth: Debug: passwd-file(username@owndomain.org,192.168.9.131,<RF4llXaXisPAqAmD>): lookup: user=username file=/var/mail/owndomain.org/passwd
Nov 16 14:20:49 auth: Debug: master userdb out: NOTFOUND        684589057
```

And i am completelly clueless what is the problem. Because it seems as if the password was found but the user is not? Password and user are looked up in the same passwd file. Have i forgotten something to setup? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok i found out the problem. Or so it seems.

In the passwd file i used the format

```
username:{scheme}password
```

but i did not added double colons for the rest of the empty values so the correct format should have been:

```
username:{scheme}password:::::
```

Issue solved.